# which mobile gis application developing is better for me

Tags: mobile, gis

i want to develop a mobile app with this features:

1-work offline on mobile and don't need to internet(disconnect mode)

2-can import layers to it in public extensions(shape file,personal geodatabase,kml)

3-can edit layers

3-have some forms and fields that fill by mobile user and save in database

i think android is better platform for developing my app,so i need a gis service that can extend in android

i know arcgis and developed web apps and desktop apps with that before,but in mobile app developping, i can't use it,because i had to use arcgisonline service to host my layers and i don't want share my map and want to host data locally and offline

let me know what i need and what platform i choose and which is better

thanks in advance......

Comment: follow my question in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45611) link

Answer (score 0):

The ArcGIS Android API is a good choice. Esri have a sample offline app available for download. We have used Mobile Flex, since we have clients who want both iOS and Android solutions. It uses ArcGIS Online but could only use local files if needed. See a demo here:

http://www.webmapsolutions.com/category/arcgis-online

--Matt

Comment: tanx @Matt.i read your solutions,those are good,i see your mobile product(GeoMobile) and see that it can work with an arcgis server,can i use that by wireless networking in out door? and can i extend this app?i need some forms and information to save on my tables

Comment: ArcGis Server installed on a device and GeoMobile configure to connect to it and load layers?